# Playing Rtmp stream in Android Application

Tags: android, stream, rtmp

hello i have followed the information on [this](http://blog.enbake.com/streaming-video-android/) link to play a rtmp stream like "rtmp://178.33.241.201:1935/teledunet/spacetoon" after configuring i am not getting any build error or syntax error but when it is run on either emulator or actual device after start a message pop ups saying "Unfortunately Application has stopped working" please help me and one thing please provide solution only regarding rtmp protocol as i am not interested in rtsp or http
thank you in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Checkout this code, it might help you!

```
$cc->headers[] = "Host: www.teledunet.com";
$cc->headers[] = "Referer: http://www.teledunet.com/";
$html = $cc->get("http://www.teledunet.com/mobile/?con");
preg_match("/var aut='\?id0=(.*?)'/", $html, $timex);
$swf = "http://www.teledunet.com/mobile/player.swf?id0=".$timex[1]."&channel=".$tmp[1];
$tmxx = $tmp[1];
preg_match("|rtmp://(.*?)/$tmxx|", $html, $r);
if (empty($r[0])){
  $r[0] = "rtmp://5.135.134.110:1935/live";
}
echo "\r\nStart of ".$tmp[0]." in progress...\r\n";
$cmd = 'rtmpdump -q -v -r "'.$r[0].'" -W "'.$swf.'" -p     "http://www.teledunet.com/mobile/?con" -y "'.$tmp[1].'" | "'.$vlc.'" --meta- title="'.$tmp[0].' (Teledunet by Darby_Crash)" - '.$out.'';
shell_exec($cmd);
```

Comment: While this code may help solve the problem, a code only answer is not high quality.   A better answer would describe what the code does, show where to insert it, tell why the the approach was taken, and link to relevant documentation.